# Initial Conditions for Inflationary Equations of Motion

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

I am attempting to solve the equation of motion for single field inflation. The equation of motion is given by
\begin{equation}
\ddot{\phi} + 3H\dot{\phi} + \frac{dV}{d\phi} = 0
\end{equation}
In conformal time, $\eta$, with $d\eta = d t/a$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2\phi}{d\eta^2} + 2H\frac{d\phi}{d\eta} + \frac{dV}{d\phi} = 0
\end{equation}
The Friedmann equation gives (assuming the inflaton energy density is the only relevant component) is:
\begin{equation}
H^2
=
\frac{1}{M_{\rm Pl}^2}
\left(
\frac{1}{2a^2}\left(\frac{d\phi}{d\eta}\right)^2 + V(\phi)
\right)
.
\end{equation}

To solve numerically, I nondimensionalize and define $a(\eta = 0) = a_e$, $H(\eta = 0) = H_e$ and the time variable $\tau = a_eH_e\eta$ such that,
\begin{equation}
\alpha = a/a_e,
\qquad 
h = H/H_e,
\qquad
\Phi = \phi/M_{\rm Pl},
\qquad 
\mathcal{V} = V/(H_e^2 M_{\rm Pl}^2)
.
\end{equation}
The equation of motion become
\begin{align}
&\Phi'' + 2\alpha h\Phi' + \alpha^2 \frac{d\mathcal{V}}{d\Phi} = 0\\
&h^2 = \left(\frac{\alpha'}{\alpha^2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{6\alpha^2}\left(\Phi'^2 + 2\alpha^2\mathcal{V}\right)
\end{align}
where $'\equiv d/d\tau$. The requirement that $\alpha(\tau = 0) = 1$ and $h(\tau = 0) = 1$ leads to the initial conditions:
\begin{align}
\alpha(\tau = 0) &= 1\\
\Phi'(\tau = 0) &= \sqrt{6 - 2\mathcal{V}(\Phi_0)}\\
\Phi(\tau = 0) &= \Phi_0
\end{align}
This leaves free the choice of $\Phi_0$. ***I am unsure what to take as the value here.*** For example, if I assume the potential to be
\begin{equation}
V(\phi) = \frac{1}{2}m_\phi^2\phi^2
\implies
\mathcal{V}(\Phi) = \frac{1}{2}\mu_\phi^2 \Phi^2
\end{equation}
with $\mu_\phi = m_\phi/H_e$, then a natural choice would be $\Phi_0 = \sqrt{6}/\mu_\phi$ so that $\Phi'(\tau = 0) = 0$. However, this implies
\begin{equation}
\Phi_0 = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{\mu_\phi}
\implies
\phi_0 > M_{\rm Pl},\quad {\rm for}\quad \mu_\phi < H_e
\end{equation}
which seems strange. The choice of $\mu_\phi\ll 1$ also is problematic numerically, so a better choice of $\Phi_0$ has other benefits.